# How to range the items in function?

Tags: python, html, django

How to make this range working in function. Whenever I limit `n`, it gives every result without limit. Here I used `Destination()` which is a class in `models.py`

```
# This is to show you
def generator(f, n, *args, **kwargs):
    return (f(*args, **kwargs) for __ in range(n))

# Here is a problem
target1 = Destination.objects.all()
for field in target1:
    [Destination(img = f'{field.img}',title = f'{field.title}') for __ in range(2)]

#models.py
class Destination(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 0):

For generator you have to use `yeild` instead of `return`.

Try something like this :

```
def generator(f, n, *args, **kwargs):
    i=0

    while i < n:
        yeild f(*args, **kwargs)
        i += 1
```

Reference : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-yield-keyword-instead-return-keyword-python/

Comment: Please check the question.